# Saving data to redux vs making API calls to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

So I have an app that relies on redux-thunk and an express backend. Would it be considered good practice to fetch data and make a post request at the same time?

Here is a code example:

```
export const getProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const { data } = await API.getProducts();
  dispatch({ type: 'GET_PRODUCTS', payload: data });
};

export const createProduct = (proData) => async (dispatch) => {
  const { data, status } = await API.createProduct(proData);
  if (status === 200) {
    dispatch(getProducts());
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is fine for most cases.

You could also consider returning the new product in the response from your express api and adding it to redux after `createProduct` finishes like:

```js
export const createProduct = (proData) => async (dispatch) => {
  const { data, status } = await API.createProduct(proData);
  if (status === 200) {
    // add product to state
    dispatch(productCreated(data));
  }
};
```

A more advanced option would be to optimistically update your store (and UI) by dispatching an event before the request finishes.

```js
export const createProduct = (proData) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(productCreatedPending(proData));
  const { data, status } = await API.createProduct(proData);
  if (status !== 200) {
    // Handle error by dispatching another action to fix the state
    // or however you want
  }
};
```

Depends how you want your UI to work